# Android: Reach Button object from a different layout

Tags: java, android

I try to reach a Button which is in a layout called `task_item.xml` but I didn't managed to do it.

Part of my code:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.task_item, null);
private Button deleteButton;

deleteButton = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I get a `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.LayoutInflater android.view.Window.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Maybe using the applicationContext LayoutInflater `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );`

Comment: I'm using your inflater know like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_item, null);
```

But I get the same error: 

``` Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference```

Comment: Are yout inflating before the `onCreate()` method?, if so, inflate after `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View inflatedView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.task_item, null);
private Button deleteButton;

deleteButton = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Make sure that the `R.id.delete_button` button is inside the `R.layout.task_item` layout.

Make sure you pass the context carefully. Like ActivityName.this. This happens when the context is null.